# groupadd: invalid group ID 'laradock' error when running docker-compose up

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

groupadd: invalid group ID 'laradock'
Service 'workspace' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -yqq &&     pecl channel-update pecl.php.net &&     groupadd -g ${PGID} laradock &&     useradd -u ${PUID} -g laradock -m laradock -G docker_env &&     usermod -p "*" laradock' returned a non-zero code: 3

Answer (score 6):

Fixed the issue by adding below line in docker .env file
WORKSPACE_PUID=1000
WORKSPACE_PGID=1000